Creating a custom MuJoCo extension
I am currently trying to simulate a robot that has motors on its joints. The motors have built-in PD controllers with a feed-forward term. How can I achieve this functionality with a single custom MuJoCo plugin?
I tried using the built-in PID extension as a template to write the PDFF controller, but even though my code compiles, I could not get MuJoCo to find and use it when I call it in the XML file. Right now, I compiled my code to a libpdff_plugin.so file, and placed it into the same folder as the XML file. Here's the python script that tries to load the XML:
import mujoco
import os

plugin_path = "libpdff_plugin.so"
os.environ["LD_PRELOAD"] = plugin_path

XML = "example.xml"
model = mujoco.MjModel.from_xml_path(XML)

print(model)

and here is the XML itself:
<mujoco>
  <extension>
    <plugin plugin="pdff">
      <instance name="pdff_instance">
        <config key="kp" value="40.0"/>
        <config key="kd" value="4"/>
        <config key="ff_setpoint" value="0"/>
        <config key="ctrl_max" value="1"/>
      </instance>
    </plugin>
  </extension>

  <worldbody>
    <body>
      <joint name="j" type="slide" axis="0 0 1" />
      <geom type="sphere" size="0.01" mass="1"/>
    </body>
  </worldbody>

  <actuator>
    <plugin joint="j" plugin="pdff" instance="pdff_instance"/>
  </actuator>
</mujoco>

The script gives the below error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File (the parent directory)/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    model = mujoco.MjModel.from_xml_path(XML)
ValueError: XML Error: unknown plugin 'pdff'
Element 'plugin', line 3

